# Find length of intersection between 2 points and a sphere

Tags: computational-geometry, geometry

I have a sphere and 2 points. The points have (x,y,z) coordinates and the sphere is defined by its centre (0,0,0) and radius R. I am trying to find the length between the 2 points which intersects the sphere. How can I script this out in Mathematica?

See below, my objective is length L:

[image]

Comment: Find the distance from center of sphere to the line.  Use that distance in the Pythagorean formula to get $L/2$.

Comment: "would it be possible to have the length of the line in the form of an equation?" - if you try following Louis's suggestion, you can get one. Look [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Point-LineDistance3-Dimensional.html) to get the explicit formula for the distance from a point to a line.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `RegionIntersection` and `RegionMeasure`. Using the examples from the other answers:

```
RegionIntersection[Ball[{0,1,0}, 2], InfiniteLine[{{0,0,0},{2,1,1}}]]
RegionMeasure@%
%//N

(* Line[{{1/3 (1-Sqrt[19]),1/6 (1-Sqrt[19]),1/6 \
(1-Sqrt[19])},{1/3 (1+Sqrt[19]),1/6 (1+Sqrt[19]),1/6 \
(1+Sqrt[19])}}] *)

(* Sqrt[38/3] *)

(* 3.55903 *)

SeedRandom[0]
RegionIntersection[Ball[{0,0,0}, 3], InfiniteLine@@RandomReal[{-9, 9}, {2, 3}]]
RegionMeasure@%

(* Line[{{2.11448,-1.73651,-1.23025},{2.49353,0.749673,1.4900\
7}}] *)

(* 3.70471 *)
```

Answer (score 3):

Lets say, you have a sphere centered at `x0,y0,z0` with radius a and a line passing through `x1,y1,z1` and `x2,y2,z2`. Then you can use `Solve`

```
{x0, y0, z0} = {0, 1, 0}
r = 2
{x1, y1, z1} = {0, 0, 0}
{x2, y2, z2} = {2, 1, 1}

intsct = {x, y, z} /. Solve[{x, y, z} ∈ InfiniteLine[{{x1, y1, z1}, {x2, y2, z2}}] 
                         && {x, y, z} ∈ Sphere[{x0, y0, z0}, r], {x, y, z}]
```

> $\{\{\frac{1}{3}\text{ (1-}\sqrt{19}\text{),}\frac{1}{6}\text{
>    (1-}\sqrt{19}\text{),}\frac{1}{6}\text{
>    (1-}\sqrt{19}\text{)$\}$,$\{$}\frac{1}{3}\text{
>    (1+}\sqrt{19}\text{),}\frac{1}{6}\text{
>    (1+}\sqrt{19}\text{),}\frac{1}{6}\text{ (1+}\sqrt{19}\text{)$\}\}$}$

```
EuclideanDistance[intsct[[1]], intsct[[2]]]//N
```

> 3.55903

```
Graphics3D[{InfiniteLine[{{x1, y1, z1}, {x2, y2, z2}}], 
PointSize[Large], Point[intsct], Opacity[0.5], Sphere[{x0, y0, z0}, r]}]
```

[image]

Comment: could i set {x0, y0, z0} = {0, 0, 0}?

Comment: also, would it be possible to have the length of the line in the form of an equation?

Comment: What do you think ;) ? For the second question, if you know the equation of the sphere and line, it is possible. You can use `Solve` to get that.

Answer (score 1):

Let

```
R = 2;
c = {0, 1, 0};
{p1, p2} = {{0, 0, 0}, {2, 1, 1}}
```

and

```
line = InfiniteLine[p1, p2];
sphere = Sphere[c, R];

pts = RegionIntersection[sphere, line]
```

[image]

```
Graphics3D[{Opacity[0.5], sphere, line, Darker@Red, PointSize[Large], pts}, Axes -> True]
```

[image]

Then

```
d = RegionDistance[line, c]
```

> $\sqrt{\frac{5}{6}}$

and

```
2 Sqrt[R^2 - d^2]
```

> $\sqrt{\frac{38}{3}}$

```
N@%
```

> 3.55903

or

```
EuclideanDistance @@ Catenate[List @@ pts] // FullSimplify
```

> $\sqrt{\frac{38}{3}}$

Comment: would it be possible to have the length of the line in the form of an equation?